# Javascript trigger request with a button?

Tags: javascript, button, request, prompt

I am learning JavaScript, I have reached a section called "creating objects", since I am a novice in programming I cant figure out how to trigger the "prompt" request by using a button, instead of being triggered when the page loads,  any idea?

```
myobjt = new Object();
var reqPrompt = prompt("Type a word:");
myobjt.mnfstInput = reqPrompt;
function mFunc() {
   document.write(this.mnfstInput);
}
myobjt.mnfstScreen = mFunc;
myobjt.mnfstScreen();
```

Comment: You should create objects in this way: `var foo = {}` :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both of the other answers are correct, and are a very good way to do it, I'll try to answer using an object

```
<script>
var myObject = {
     input: "",
     popup: function(){
         alert("Hello, " + this.input);
     },
     setInput: function(){
         this.input = prompt("Enter Name");
     }
 }
 </script>
 <button type="button" onclick="myObject.setInput()">Input</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="myObject.popup()">Output</button>
```

**Edit:**
https://jsfiddle.net/u1yfsp4z/4/

Answer (score 1):

Add a button in your **HTML** like this one:

```
<button id="clickMe">click here!</button>
```

Then retrieve this button in **your script** and use an event listener to listen the click events:

```
var button = document.getElementById('clickMe');

button.addEventListener('click', trigger);

function trigger() {
    // all your code :)
}
```

Comment: `getElementById('#clickMe');`?

Answer (score 1):

In your html create a button

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

In javascript add an event handler:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    var question = prompt("What is the meaning of life?");
    //do whatever you want to do with the answer
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML `onclick` attribute on the `button`

```
<button onclick='add()'>Add property</button>
```

I noticed that you are using `document.write`, keep in mind `document.write` will overwrite the whole page.

```js
var myobjt = new Object();

function add(){
  var reqPrompt = prompt("Type a word:");
  myobjt.newProp = reqPrompt;
  mFunc();
}

function mFunc() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myobjt);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='add()'>Add property</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: oh! You beat me to it! I was going to mention adding a result paragraph.